# Remove minimum from list without min() in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I am trying to remove the minimum value from a list of randomly generated numbers without using the minimum function or the remove function.

I created a function `minremo`, but I am unsure of what the return value should be to make it actually work. Thus far, I have a method of removing the minimum.

```
def minremo(lst):
    lst.sort()
    lst.reverse()
    lst.pop()
    return n

import random
number_list = []
for count in range(10):
    number = random.randint(1, 100)
    number_list.append(number)
print(number_list)
print(minremo(number_list))
```

The algorithms to remove the minimum works at file-level scope though:

```
import random
number_list = []
for count in range(10):
    number = random.randint(1, 100)
    number_list.append(number)
print(number_list)
number_list.sort()
number_list.reverse()
number_list.pop()
print(minremo(number_list))
```

But it does not work within the function itself. I'm not sure what I should return within the function. What should the return be within this function?

Comment: `return n` What is `n`? There's your problem

Comment: @petar It was a placeholder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return the list that you just modified (`lst`).

```
def minremo(lst):
    lst.sort()
    lst.reverse()
    lst.pop()
    return lst
```